# Append new column to DF by subtracting data from 2 columns that could change if there is missing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several date columns that can be used to determine the age of a product when it failed. Ideally, I would just be able to subtract Install Date from Incident Date to get the age of the product at failure, but I don't have all the install dates. This is the most accurate option though so I have to try to use this column. The next column to try is shipping date (transaction date), and some of those are missing so the last option is to use build date and that data is all there.

```
age = final_df['Incident Date'] - final_df['Install Date']
if age >= datetime.timedelta(0):
    failure_age = age
elif final_df['Install Date'] == 'NaT' | age < datetime.timedelta(0):
    age = final_df['Incident Date'] - final_df['Transaction Date']
    if age >= datetime.timedelta(0):
    failure_age = age
    elif final_df['Transaction Date'] == 'NaT' | age < 
    datetime.timedelta(0):
        final_age = final_df['Incident Date'] - final_df['Build Date']
```

The current error I am getting is that the truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.time(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Try parens around your conditionals. For example: `elif (final_df['Install Date'] == 'NaT')  | (age < datetime.timedelta(0))`. Sometimes you need to be explicit about order of operations.

Comment: using `age.any()` and replacing `datetime.timedelta(0)` to 0 can solve the problem. I think

Comment: As age is not a single value, so you can try above method or this one `(age >=datetime.timedelta(0)).any()`